# Using SSAO For Blended Objects

Tags: ssao

What is the best (most common) approach using SSAO with forward renderer for blended objects?

Comment: what do you mean by "Blended" objects? Do you mean transparency?

Comment: Where are you starting from? Do you already have a forward renderer with SSAO and are looking to extend it to work with transparency, or do you have a forward renderer with transparency that you’re looking to add SSAO to, or what?

Comment: Yes, I mean translucency.

Comment: I have a deferred render for opaque objects, forward render for translucent objects. I use SSAO for opaque objects but I'm not sure what is the best way to use SSAO for blended objects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.